# Modifying parent class attribute from child class method

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I have two classes, one parent called `Organization` and one child called `Employee`. `Organization` has an attribute called `org_size` which I want to be able to increment when I call my `add_employee` method that belongs to the `Employee` class.

```
class Organization( object ):
    def __init__(self, org_name):
        self.org_name = org_name
        self.org_size = 0
        self.org_revenue = 0
        self.num_placements = 0
    
    def get_org_size(self):
        return self.org_size

class Employee( Organization ):
    def __init__(self, employee_name, comission_rate):
        self.employee_name = employee_name
        self.comission_rate = comission_rate
        self.total_comission = 0
    
    def add_employee(employee_name, comission_rate):
        employee = Employee(employee_name, comission_rate)
        self.org_size += 1
        return employee

team = Organization("My Sales Team")
emp = Employee("Bob", 15)
```

Regardless if I call `team.org_size` or `team.get_org_size()`, I get an answer of 0, instead of the expected 1, as I want to increment `org_size` as part of calling the `add_employee()` method. I tried adding a super() to `Employee` but then whenever I called `add_employee` it caused issues with requiring the `org_name` argument from `Organization`.

What do I need to do with `Employee` class in order to modify attributes in `Organization`?

Comment: That inheritance structure doesn't make sense. `class Employee( Organization ):` is saying that an employee is a kind of organization.

Comment: If I change the order and try to make ```Organization``` inherit ```Employee``` it doesn't help either

Comment: When you describe an OO design out loud it should make sense. Does it make sense to say either of these: An employee *is an* organization. An organization *is an* employee. Not really. That indicates you should probably use a *has-a* relationship instead of an *is-a* relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship between Organization and Employee is a "HAS A" relationship, not an "IS A" relationship. An Employee is not a KIND OF an organization, she is a MEMBER of an organization.

```
class Organization():
    def __init__(self, org_name):
        self.org_name = org_name
        self.org_size = 0
        self.org_revenue = 0
        self.num_placements = 0
        self.employees = []
    
    def add_employee(self, employee_name, comission_rate):
        employee = Employee(employee_name, comission_rate)
        self.employees.append(employee)
        return employee
    
    def get_org_size(self):
        return len(self.employees)

class Employee():
    def __init__(self, employee_name, comission_rate):
        self.employee_name = employee_name
        self.comission_rate = comission_rate
        self.total_comission = 0

team = Organization("My Sales Team")
bob = team.add_employee("Bob", 15)
```